# Django Duplicate Values in ChoiceField

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and am having issues with the forms.py. I am pulling values from a database via Models.Py and then using those objects as a dropdown list on my Django page.

For example, I have Car Data stored in a database:

Honda | Accord | Black | 2016

Toyota | Camry | Red | 2014

Ford | Fusion | White | 2018

Honda | Civic | Silver | 2020

Toyota | Corolla | Black | 2010

And so on. In models.py, I have:

```
class MyCars(models.Model):

    make_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        all_cars = []
        return self.make_name

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'my_cars'
```

Then in my form.py I do something along the line of:

```
all_cars = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyCars.objects.all())
```

The problem is I will then have duplicate values for Honda, Toyota etc, when I only need Honda to appear once on the dropdown.  Any suggestions/ideas to filter through this?

Comment: You want to select the make_name only? Or would `<make_name> <model_name>` be correct?

Comment: No - I would want to separate the Make and Model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you face the problem of your tables not being normalized. Considering that many cars may have the same make and there may be new makes over time you really should have a **Model** for make and have a foreign key from `MyCars` to `Make`.

```
class Make(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MyCars(models.Model):
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cars")
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        all_cars = []
        return self.make_name

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'my_cars'
```

Now in your form:

```
all_cars = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Make.objects.all())
```

Also the name `MyCars` should be singular(`MyCar`) as model names are meant to be singular (check `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural` in your case `verbose_name_plural` ends up to be `my carss`).

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  If I understand this correctly, this would require a new database for the Car Makes in order to add values to 'all_cars' in forms?  Otherwise it will return blank values?

Comment: @MC2020 A new database? no. A new table **in** the same database? yes. Also you would need to make entries for the Make model / make form for users to make entires. Before finalizing one's models one should always normalize them (search up on database normalization). Also there might be a few obvious improvements you can make on my suggestion, for instance setting `unique=True` on the field `name` in the `Make` model, etc.

Comment: Right - I meant a new table.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MC2020 note that above implementation is still not normalized. One can split model_name (potentially will have duplicate values) also into a separate table for instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're use `PostgreSQL`, change

`all_cars = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyCars.objects.all())`

to

`all_cars = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyCars.objects.distinct("model_name"))`

Comment: Thank you - this at least points me in the right direction. Unfortunately it looks like the is not supported by MySQL.  Any other ideas?

Comment: `raw sql` or `annotate` by Count and `filter` by less than 2.

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter your queries in forms.py. Currently you are just grabbing everything with MyCars.objects.all(). Not sure about the exact syntax, but the Django docs is a great place to look.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/

If I remember correctly it is distinct, but not 100% sure.
https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/distinct.html

Answer (score 0):

You are not having duplicates, you problem is that your **str** function returns the self.make_name, so, your queryset is the full list of cars, and as the Toyota Camry, and Toyota Corolla have the same make_name you see them with the same name, but in the back side you are just showing that attribute. You can use the distinct function over your query to change the attribute, or you can directly change the **str** function over your car model to adapt to what you need (you can concatenate multiple attributes). Here an example:

```
def __str__(self):
    all_cars = []
    return f"${self.make_name} - {self.model_name}"
```