# Create a ChoiceFilter with all the unique values in a specific field (Django)

Tags: django, django-filter

I have a `Car` model with some of the following fields:

```py
#models.py
from django.conf import settings

class Car(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE,null=True)
    tag = models.CharField(max_lenght=16) #User-specified tag for each car
    n_wheels = models.IntegerField()
       .
       .
```

The idea is that each user can create a `Car` where the `tag` field is whatever the user wants e.g `personal`, `work-car`, `for leasing` etc.

In my HTML there is a list of all the cars the user has added, but I would like to create a filter, such that the user can filter on the `tag` to quickly find the list of the wanted cars.

Since the `tag` is completely user-defined, the only restriction is the length of the tag (i.e if the user decides to create 4 cars with the tags `["Workzz","workzz","wOrK","WORK"]` it is allowed and treated as 4 different tags). The expected number of different tags for each user is low thus I would like some drop-down filter for the `tag` field.

Since I do not know in advance what `tag` a user wants to set for each car, I cannot create a `ChoiceField`, thus I struggle to find a way, to get all unique `tag` values for a specific (logged in) user, and put them in a DropDown-filter.

One way I have thought of is; in the view, load the unique tags for the given user, create a Form with a choice-field (with the tags) and create a filter based on that form.
It does seem like a dirty-work-around that might not scale well, but that's the only idea I can come up with.

Comment: Your `brand` here should ideally be a `ForeignKey` to a _model_ not a `CharField`. Currently your database schema is not _normalized_, making it difficult for you to deal with data. Please research a bit on [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Why should it? Then I need to change all my fields to Foreign keys and models, if I plan on filtering on them in the future. That does not sound right

Comment: It is a simple principle, let's say a user comes and enters `kia`, another enters `Kia`, some other comes and makes a spelling mistake and enters `Kiia`, all of them meant the same thing here but now you are stuck with this data that does not match, if this had been a foreign key the user would have been _restricted_ to a set of values that existed in the other table. Plus you might later decide that you need to store some more data about the brand itself, in which case you will end up making a model for it anyway. In the simplest terms of an ER model, Brand is an _Entity_ not an attribute.

Comment: @CutePoison: database normalization usually makes databases smaller, more efficient and performance more predictable, and easy to alter data with a minimal amount of queries. One of the key aspects of normalization is to avoid *data duplication*.

Comment: In fact here is a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66210721/django-duplicate-values-in-choicefield) I have answered before (also on cars and their makes) :)

Comment: I left out some information to make the question shorter and more easy - but I can see that did more harm than good since that might've masked the actual structure of the problem. I have updated the question to mirror the actual problem and apologize for the inconvenience

Comment: Does your link still propose the best solution for the problem?

Comment: Ah I see, that does make it less of an entity and more of an attribute, in that case you could set it's choices in the forms `__init__` method. (It is often important to make good examples, as modeling quite depends on the domain and no one solution fits all)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set choices in dynamic with Django choicefield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028731/how-to-set-choices-in-dynamic-with-django-choicefield) Also you might want to look at [`AllValuesFilter` (django-filter)](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#allvaluesfilter) from the package django-filter